# Trouble stubbing getter method in firebase-admin with sinon

Tags: javascript, firebase, sinon, firebase-admin

I'm trying to develop unit tests for cloud functions. Some of them call `firebase-admin.messaging().sendToDevice()` to deliver notifications that I don't want to actually send during testing.

[My reference in Firebase docs](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/04f7089de3e1cd546fe6dfeed440306e1984f193/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/test/test.offline.js#L105-L117)

[Sinon Stubs Reference](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.5/stubs/)

[image: Sinon Stub Get]

I'd like to know why `Object.defineProperty` is working but `stub.get()` (the commented out section) does not. I have a concern it might not get restored using `sinon.restore()`. By not work I mean it uses the real methods and sends a notification.  Thank you.

```
        it('should return resolved promise for success', function(done) {

            const num = 99;
            const messagingStub = sinon.stub();
            const sendStub = sinon.stub();

            Object.defineProperty(admin, 'messaging', { get: () => messagingStub });
            // sinon.stub(admin, 'messaging').get(function getterFn() {
            //     return messagingStub;
            // });
            messagingStub.returns({sendToDevice: sendStub});
            sendStub.returns(Promise.resolve({successCount: num}));
```

Comment: The example you're looking at used Sinon 4, perhaps it did not work with that version. If you're worried about triggering a message during the test, you could initialize firebase-admin with the credentials for a test project (using the free plan)

Comment: I used sinon 6.3.5 and the syntax in their docs I linked (the commented out code) but it didn't work but I expected it to. The `Object.defineProperty` from the firebase example did work. My concern is I'm missing something since I don't believe this change is reversed when calling `sinon.restore()`

Comment: I think the issue is that `sinon.stub(obj, prop)` only works when the property is a function, but Firebase Admin uses a getter to return the function (just like with `Object.defineProperty`). You can manually restore the original.

Comment: @Sidney From what I understand from the Sinon docs (I added an image) is that the `stub.get()` method is for replacing getters, which is what I tried to use. I'm not sure how to manually restore the original getter method. I'll have to look into that.